# Can I connect an amplifier to a Crystal Radio?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-analysis, radio, speakers

I am wanting to create a crystal radio that connects to my amplifier (It is for a guitar and has 3.5mm and 1/4" jacks). The diagram is as shown:
[image: b]

Would this be possible and work?  If not, please describe how I could make it work.

Comment: Have you done any research on the subject? If so please post your findings. Research is required before posting a question, both searching EE.SE and the internet.

Comment: @laptop2d I have tried to find out how to do this but I didn't find anything or didn't know if what I found was right.  I really don't know much about what I am doing.  I am really new to circuitry.  I understand only a few basic things

Comment: I would connect the lead from the diode to both the tip and ring (left and right) terminals o fthe 3.5mm jack - you won't get stereo sound from a crystal radio.  As you've drawn it, you would only get sound in the left earpiece.

Answer (score 1):

The crystal radio gets all of its miniscule power directly from the energy in the radio signal that it picks up. It is tiny. As a result it can only power a high impedance (high resistance to AC signal) crystal earpiece. The input impedance of these is typically 20 kΩ. (This surprised me as I always considered them much higher.)

Your guitar amplifier, on the other hand, is designed to amplify a signal from a guitar pickup. This will be much-much stronger than the radio signal and so the amplifier may not be sensitive enough to play it loud.

It won't damage anything to try and should be quite instructive.

[image]

*Figure 1. Crystal earpiece innards. Source: [The Trouble With Ceramic Earpieces made by Eagle or Altai and Others](http://www.usefulcomponents.com/main_contents/information/crystal_earpieces/crystal_earpiece_problems.html).*

Thanks to @robert bristow-johnson for correcting me on earpiece theory. I found an interesting article, linked above, which goes into some detail on the internal construction.

Comment: Thanks for the response but are you saying that this design could work?  Read a bunch of words that I didn't honestly understand well

Comment: uhm, tens of \$\text{M}\Omega\$ ?  i built a crystal radio back in the 60s when i was a kid and they came with headphones.  of course they weren't stereo headphones that you would listen to rock-n-roll with.  they were these communication headphones like you would see in WW2 movies.  i remember unscrewing the earpiece and seeing very thin enameled copper windings.  i don't remember what the input impedance was, but tens of megs sounds like the highest resistance i have ever seen a resistor for.  about the next thing to an insulator.

Comment: i think you get the most power out of the crystal radio when you match the impedance of the headphones with the output impedance of the audio output of the radio.  i would have to think about it a bit, with tank-circuit, and i dunno exactly how the half-wave rectifier would affect the computation of output impedance, but i would bet it would have something to do with the character impedance of the antenna and of free space.  i would expect the guitar amp to have a much higher input impedance, so it wouldn't load down the radio output, but it might affect the tuning.

Comment: I built a crystal radio a few years after you. :^) Mine didn't work so I pretty much stuck to signals in wires after that. I would have thought that they would need at least a transistor or two to drive headphones. Meanwhile, I've read up a little on the crystal earpieces: you are right, the impedance is more like 20 kΩ at audio at least. Edit in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a telephone amplifier which is powered by a 9 volt battery for testing crystal radio circuits. I've also modified old telephone conference call phone devices for use as small DC powered sound amplifiers to good effect in the shop for general self contained sound amplification devices for use with crystal radios as well. I believe both are hi impedance amplifiers.